# Finding the $N^{th}$ term In binomial expansion for arbitrary power

Tags: binomial-theorem

How do I find the $n^{th}$ term in the binomial expansion of any index.

Ex: Find the $4^{th}$ term of  $(1+2x)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Maybe talk a little about your intuition/ what you already know so that people can construct you a solid non-redundant answer

Comment: I know the way to find the nth term in the binomial expansion of a positive index and I need the answer to be in form of the binomial coefficients ie ( ncr ) hope u understood

Comment: Then edit the question/ add your intuition and what you've tried so far. I don't know the answer to your question, but I know if you show part of your attempt, people will be more likely to give good answers.

Comment: I tried using the general term in binomial expansion of arbitrary index using the notations of binomial coefficients (nc1,nc2...) hope u understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Start from the general expansion of $`\,(1+u)^\alpha$:
$$(1+u)^\alpha=1+\alpha u+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} u^2+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!} u^3+\dots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1)}{n!} u^n+\dotsm$$

If you substitute $\,\alpha=-\dfrac 12$ and $u=2x$, you'll ind the coefficient of $x^n$ is eventually the signed product of the first $n$ odd integers:
$$(-1)^n1\cdot 3\cdot 5\dotsm(2n-1).$$
This results from the simplification of:
$$\binom{-\frac 12}{n} (2x)^n $$
where $\dbinom{-\frac 12}{n}$ is the *generalised binomial coefficient:
$$\dbinom{-\frac 12}{n}=\frac{-\frac12\bigl(-\frac12-1\bigr)\bigl(-\frac12-2\bigr)\dotsm\bigl(-\frac12-n+1\bigr)}{n!}$$

Comment: I tried using it but it wouldn't be fruitful when the index is of a higher value ryt

Comment: I'm sorry, but, not being a native English speaker, I don't understand the `ryt` acronym.

Comment: Ryt = right Besides I used the ncr notation (permutations and combinations ) hope u understand

Comment: I see. Usually I prefer the binomial notation. The result I gave was simplified by the $2^n$  factor that comes from $(2x)^n$.

Comment: Exactly right but what my question is that when the exponent of x increases it wouldn't be fruitful to use the binomial notation

Comment: What would be fruitful then? I gave a binomial notation (or with $C_{-\frac12}^n$, but it amounts to the same), and a simplified result.

Comment: Then you'd have to write something like $$\binom{-\frac12}{100}2^{100}$$ What else do you want to write?

Comment: Maybe do you expect the final result as:$$(-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)?$$

Comment: Sry but I'm not that good with the notations could please help me out with that

Comment: I don't need the final result but the procedure bro

Comment: But I got it thank you for the solution Bernard